# Representing finite state machine as an RDF?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, fsm, state-machine

I would like to know if a finite state machine could be represented as an RDF? Any reference or example would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it involves SDL, then it might be worth looking at the project below:

http://www.tmrfindia.org/ijcsa/v7i12.pdf

Comment: Link is not working anymore. I would appreciate an updated version. Thanks.